# WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager

Tags: linux, wso2, enterprise, mobility

I've downloaded the binary Enterprise Mobility Manager from Official Website.
But, when I tried to run the ./wso2server.sh appeared error such as:

"log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout]."

But, on lib/ directory has **org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging-4.2.0.jar** file.

Please see on below list.

```
$ls -alh lib/
total 1016K
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 4.0K Feb 18 00:57 .
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root 4.0K Feb 25 14:48 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 220K Sep  4 16:29 ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 274K Sep  4 15:35 commons-lang-2.6.0.wso2v1.jar
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4.0K Sep  4 12:25 endorsed
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 410K Sep  4 14:53 org.wso2.carbon.logging-4.2.0.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  67K Sep  4 15:32 org.wso2.carbon.server-4.2.0.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  19K Sep  4 16:29 org.wso2.ciphertool-1.0.0-wso2v2.jar
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4.0K Sep  4 12:25 tomcat
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  425 Sep  4 12:25 transactions.properties
```

Comment: can you please post your complete log - probably in pastebin?

Comment: Where can I get the complete log?

Comment: it's available in `repository/logs/wso2carbon.log`

Answer (score 1):

Set read/write permission to root directory of the product (typically wso2mobileserver-1.0.0 ). 
If you are still getting the same error, please post the complete log.